# Comma separated number/function in parenthesis in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, dot.js

I read a [line](https://github.com/olado/doT/blob/e86a9681f770bc99ef562dada4884ebb5dee8e28/doT.js#L28) from [doT.js](https://github.com/olado/doT):

```
var global = (function(){ return this || (0||eval)('this'); }());
```

After it was [minified](https://github.com/olado/doT/blob/e86a9681f770bc99ef562dada4884ebb5dee8e28/doT.min.js):

```
l=function(){return this||(0,eval)("this")}();
```

So what is the `(0,eval)`, I mean what does the comma do?

I played in Chrome's console, `(0,1)`, `(2,1)`, `(2,{})`, `2,1`, etc, it always returns the last one.

Comment: Do we know why they used `(0||eval)` in the first place?

Comment: It very well might be to get code analyzers to shut up about the fact that they're using the evil `eval` at all. But I'm just as confused as you are.

Comment: @Len They want an "indirect call to `eval`": https://github.com/olado/doT/issues/26#issuecomment-5669788

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The comma operator evaluates both and always returns the last.  Much like you said.

You can read up on the comma operator: http://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2011/04/04/the-javascript-comma-operator/

Even though I have no idea the purpose of (0||eval)... (0,eval) is the equivalent and one less character.

Comment: In the "Indirect calls to eval" section of the linked page, it explains that by using `(0,eval)`, "we can use the comma operator to fashion an indirect call to eval which will force it to execute in the global context".